# 'this' undefined inside class method

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

This works:

```
class C {
    constructor(p1, p2) {
        this.p1 = 0;
        this.p2 = [];
        this.setP1(p1);
        p2.forEach(p => this.addP2(p));
    }
    setP1(p) { this.p1 = p }
    addP2(p) { this.p2.push(p) }
}

let c = new C(10,[20]);
console.log(c);
```

> ```
> C { p1: 10, p2: [ 20 ] }
> ```

But this doesn't:

```
class C {
    constructor(p1, p2) {
        this.p1 = 0;
        this.p2 = [];
        this.setP1(p1);
        p2.forEach(this.addP2); // <- changed here
    }
    setP1(p) { this.p1 = p }
    addP2(p) { this.p2.push(p) }
}

let c = new C(10,[20]);
console.log(c);
```

> ```
> addP2(p) { this.p2.push(p) }
>                 ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'p2' of undefined
> ```

And there are two things I don't understand:

- **Why does it work?** In both cases, `setP1` is not explicitly [bound](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to `this`, so how come it successfully updates the `p1` property in the first case? Shouldn't it execute in a context where `this` is `undefined` and throw a `Cannot read property 'p1' of undefined`?
- **Why doesn't it work?** `p2.forEach(p => this.addP2(p));` is apparently equivalent to `p2.forEach(this.addP2);` because `addP2` takes only one argument. What is happening that makes the first work, but the second crash?

Comment: For second case, think of it like `callback = this.addP2; callback(item, index, arr);`. Then there's no calling context. Use arrow function like in first case, or `.bind`, or pass another argument to `forEach` to provide a `this`

Comment: `p2.forEach(p => this.addP2(p));` is equivalent to `p2.forEach(this.addP2.bind(this));`